# Delete quotes between quotes

Tags: regex

Remove all quotes and special characters between quotes.

I have this line: `"The quick "brown-fox" "jumps" over the lazy dog"`, and what I'm trying to do is keep the quotes on the ends, but remove all quotes and special characters between them so for example this line would become: `"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"`.

I have this little bit of RegEx to find quoted strings:  `(["'])(?:\\\1|.)*?\1`

However; what I'm trying to do is actually remove special characters between quotes.  I only just recently discovered regular expressions and it can do alot, but I'm still learning.

Comment: Your question isn't entirely well-defined. Do you simply want to remove all quotes except the leftmost and the rightmost? Or do you want to remove quotes which are separated only by alphabetics? What if *"he said "he said" to me"* were to be added to your example? What about ill-formed input like *"he said* or *"she "said*?

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```js
let string = `"The quick "brown-fox" "jumps" over the lazy dog"`.replace(/(?<=.)"(?=.)/g, "");

console.log(string);
```

JS Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/jorgesanure/vca2gsxm/

For use it from sublime, copy only this `(?<=.)"(?=.)`
[image]

Comment: JS does not support positive lookbehind. Feel free to present this working example: https://regex101.com/r/FE4XKN/1

Comment: Excellent! That was fast however my apologies good sir; I should have mentioned I'm doing this from Sublime Text.  As I understand it there are different types of RegEx and this doesn't seem to work from Sublime.

Comment: just copy this: `(?<=.)"(?=.)`

Comment: You people are amazing.  Worked like a charm and so simple too.  Surprised I was not able to arrive at this.   Thanks so much you guys :)

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure there are much efficient ways/expressions to do that, yet I couldn't think of one, maybe we'd then try three expressions, one similar to:

```
((?:[^"\r\n-])*)|((?!(^"|"$)).)+?
```

and a replacement of `$1` followed by a <kbd>space</kbd>, which would print:

```
"The quick   brown  fox     jumps   over the lazy dog "
```

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/BAOfC9/1/)

Then, with a second expression,

```
\s{2,}
```

and replace with a single space:

```
 "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog "
```

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/QY0eVP/1/)

and with a third expression of,

```
\s*"\s*
```

and a replacement of `"`, we'd probably get:

```
"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
```

#### [Demo 3](https://regex101.com/r/BAOfC9/1/)

> The undesired chars goes in the char class: `[^"\r\nUndesired_Chars_Goes_here-]`

Comment: Thanks for the response Emma.  I'm still learning regex, and it's really cool there are more than one ways to get at this.  What if I wanted to remove quotes within quotes but only after a certain word?

For example:
{Here is my text: "The quick "red fox" jumped over the "lazy dog" and it was fun"}

This is what I have, but I may be confused on how to apply it:
(?<=Text:.)(?<=.)"(?=.)

Comment: The idea is to remove all quotes within the string after (text:) so it looks like this:
{Here is my text: "The quick red fox jumped over the lazy dog and it was fun"}